# How can I get a BeautifulSoup object from BeautifulSoup.find()?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is likely to be a rookie question, however I have read the entire bs4 documentation and am struggling to find a solution to my question.

I basically have a BeautifulSoup object, from which I am calling .find() to locate a certain div, and I want to then call .find_all() on this div. **I have tried something like this:**

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "lxml")

competition = soup.find("div", class_="accordion-competition__content_main").contents

events = competition.find_all("div", class_="sport-event-card")

for event in competition:

    print("EVENT: ", event)
```

To no avail.

How do you filter through a filtered section with BS4? Any help is greatly appreciated. I keep stumbling upon this issue and am yet to find a suitable solution for filtering through a section.

Answer (score 0):

```py
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "lxml")

competition = soup.find("div", {"class": "accordion-competition__content_main"}) # get competition node

events = competition.find_all("div", {"class": "sport-event-card"}) # find inside competition node

for event in events:
    print("EVENT: ", event)
```